# Weird caching using Django and Chosen

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-chosen

I have a field where you can delete one or more customers. However if certain conditions are met, the deletion is prevented. The problem is that when the form validation comes back with the error message, the customer is not there anymore and this causes confusion among the users whether it has been removed for not. For example:

Let's pretend I want to remove the customer bellow:

[image]

An error:

[image]

However the customer is not in the field anymore. It seems to be due to some kind of caching with Javascript - I am not sure. If I refresh the page I can see the customer has not been removed, because it comes back.

How can I make sure the value comes back after the validation?

Comment: needs more info.  How are you validating?  Are you posting to the server to validate and returning response to client? AJAX validate? Client-side validation using javascript?  What javascript lib are you using to validate?  Some or the relevant code would probably be helpful.

Comment: The validation is done through Django. It's submitted through a POST and regenerated back fulfilling a few variables in the template, such as the error message. I have been using it for a few projects and I don't think I have seen this problem before. That's why I wanted to see if someone around here had seen in a combination of Django + Chosen.

Comment: I have used Django + Chosen on past projects and not had an issue like this.

Comment: You haven't shown any code so it is hard to see what is happening.  But remember you can't rely on the POSTed data to refill the selected Customers.  The user removed the Customer, it is not in the POSTed data.  You have to fetch the data from DB to be able to properly refill the selected customer you do not want removed or use another mechanism to cache/store that data so you can refill the customer on response.